# Is Spring Rest Controllers Singleton?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a sample Spring Rest application.
I have several clients accessing an API in the Spring Rest application. The API checks whether a job has started or not against the MSSQL DB that we use.
If the Job status in DB is in started status, it will pick the record and update its status to inprogress and return the details of the Job as the response to the API and based on that the client will do some processing.

We have observed that, more than one client is picking up the same Job which is in started status and updates it to inprogress and pass the response to the client. So, it ends up like the same job is being processed by multiple clients.

We tried to resolve this by adding a synchronized block and enclosed the DB call that picks the record in started state and update it to inprogress. The DB call resides in the service layer. But still the duplicate issue is there.

If the controller and the subsequent layers like service and DAO layers are singleton then, when multiple API calls hit the web app, the synchronized block of code should be executed by one request at a time. But that is not what we see practically.

Could someone please help to resolve this issue?

Comment: The syncronized keyword will work only in the scope of a single JVM instance. Can you please verify how many instances of app you are running?

Comment: Why not try use database level lock mechanism like `select ... for update` in a transaction.

Comment: We are running a single instance of the webapp. The Client referred here is a standalone  jar running in jetty server which just hits the webapp via REST API to fetch the started job details

Answer (score 0):

Actually Rest Controllers are Thread Safe it means it is capable of handling each HTTP requests unique. Also when you try to access the Rest Controller it creates a separate session id in browser you can also check that using developer console. Here you are trying to access same DB and change the status as inprogress, so there is a chance for the next api to fetch details of the previous session.. so try to modify the Rest API without modifying status in DB every time or you can do something like, if the DB is accessed by one API then the other API should not be able to access DB until the first connection is closed. Hope this can work for you.

Comment: Yes this works for me "if the DB is accessed by one API then the other API should not be able to access DB until the first connection is closed. Hope this can work for you." . Could you please suggest a way to do that.

Comment: Yes everytime an API hits the DB check the status if it is inprogress or not used, if it is not used then let that API to access it else return a message stating that it is already in use, and remember everytime a connection is closed, it should modify the inprogress value in DB